# Python Pickle File Permissions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I'm new to python and am trying to write a program that keeps track of an amount of money, numbers or whatever. You can add or subtract to your amount and it is saved to a file, or check the amount you currently have. I had it working using this code

```
  import pickle

  num = 0
  toDo = input("would you like to load or add/subtract? ")

  if toDo == "add":
    a = float(input("How much do you want to add? "))
    pickle_in = open("Python", "rb")
    newNum = pickle.load(pickle_in)
    newNum = newNum + a
    print("Current balance:", newNum)
    pickle_out = open("Python","wb")
    pickle.dump(newNum, pickle_out)
    pickle_out.close()

  if toDo == "subtract":
    a = float(input("How much do you want to subtract? "))
    pickle_in = open("Python", "rb")
    newNum = pickle.load(pickle_in)
    newNum = newNum - a
    print("Current balance:", newNum)
    pickle_out = open("Python","wb")
    pickle.dump(newNum, pickle_out)
    pickle_out.close()


  if toDo == "load":
    pickle_in = open("Python", "rb")
    newNum = pickle.load(pickle_in)
    print("Current balance:", newNum)
```

This was working fine, the file was loading properly, everything was good, until today (about 24 hours later) when I tried to run this program again, attempting to load the current amount, and it gave me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dom\Desktop\amount.py", line 34, in <module>
    pickle_in = open("Python", "rb")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Python'
```

I then tried using the os.chmod function but I'm not 100% sure I used it properly.

```
import pickle
import os, sys, stat



num = 0
toDo = input("would you like to load or add/subtract? ")

if toDo == "add":
  a = float(input("How much do you want to add? "))
  pickle_in = os.chmod("Python", "rb")
  newNum = pickle.load(pickle_in)
  newNum = newNum + a
  print("Current balance:", newNum)
  pickle_out = open("Python","wb")
  pickle.dump(newNum, pickle_out)
  pickle_out.close()


if toDo == "subtract":
  a = float(input("How much do you want to subtract? "))
  pickle_in = os.chmod("Python", "rb")
  newNum = pickle.load(pickle_in)
  newNum = newNum - a
  print("Current balance:", newNum)
  pickle_out = open("Python","wb")
  pickle.dump(newNum, pickle_out)
  pickle_out.close()


if toDo == "load":
  pickle_in = os.chmod("Python", "rb")
  newNum = pickle.load(pickle_in)
  print("Current balance:", newNum)
```

it seemed i got past the permission problem using chmod, but then i got this error when trying to load, add or subtract.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dom\Desktop\amount.py", line 11, in <module>
    pickle_in = os.chmod("Python", "rb")
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Not sure if i'm not using the chmod function properly or what. Could anyone tell me how to fix this and/or why it stopped working?

Answer (score 2):

Do not automatically change permissions. That is neither helpful nor necessary.

First of all, sort out your current permission problem. You can start by using another name instead of `'Python'`, which is completely unrelated to your application and likely to be confused with the python binary. How about `'amount.storage'`? If necessary (and only if necessary, which it is not by default), use `ls` and `chmod` (in the command line, not in your program) to sort out permissions. If you need help with that, [ask at our sister site superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/ask?tags=chmod). You can use `touch amount.storage` to try creating the file, and `rm amount.storage` (both in the command line, *not* in the Python shell) to delete it.

Afterwards, make sure to correctly open your file. Since you're doing it multiple times, it pays to have [functions](https://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) so that you don't need to copy and paste your code. Let's start with the loading function:

```
import pickle

FILENAME = "amount.storage"

def load():
    with open(FILENAME, "rb") as f:
        return pickle.load(f)
```

By using a [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/errors.html#predefined-clean-up-actions), we make sure to close the file even if an error occurs. Speaking of errors, we should most definitely handle the file not being present. Let's add an [exception handler](https://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/errors.html#tut-handling):

```
def load():
    try:
        with open(FILENAME, "rb") as f:
            return pickle.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return 0  # start with 0 if no storage present
```

Saving is then easy; open with mode `wb`:

```
def save(amount):
    with open(FILENAME, "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(amount, f)
```

Now that we got these helper functions, let's use them in the whole program:

```
import pickle

FILENAME = "amount.storage"


def load():
    try:
        with open(FILENAME, "rb") as f:
            return pickle.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return 0  # start with 0 if no storage present


def save(amount):
    with open(FILENAME, "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(amount, f)


num = load()
toDo = input("would you like to load or add/subtract? ")

if toDo == "add":
    a = float(input("How much do you want to add? "))
    newNum = num + a
    save(newNum)
elif toDo == "subtract":
    a = float(input("How much do you want to subtract? "))
    newNum = num - a
    save(newNum)
else:
    newNum = num

print("Current balance:", newNum)
```

Note that by removing all the code you copied and pasted, this new program is much more easier to follow, and much more easier to change.

Apart from more operations, one of the next steps could also be to eschew pickle, which opens a potential security hole by allowing anyone who can write to the file to inject arbitrary Python code. Instead, how about [json](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/json.html)? All you need to do is replace the three instances of `pickle` above with `json` and delete the storage file once/name it `amount.json`, as its current state will not be a valid JSON file. A plus would be that JSON is human-readable; encoding a number will simply result in the number as a human-readable string (and nothing more) being written to the file.